# I am parsing some HTML by phantomjs, how can I set the language for what I parse?

Tags: html-parsing, phantomjs

I would like to parse the English version html source code of  by phantomjs.

Followings are my codes:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();

if (phantom.args.length === 0) {
    console.log('Usage: google.js keyword');
    phantom.exit();
}

address = "http://www.google.com"
keyword = phantom.args[0];

page.open(address, function (status) {
    if (status !== 'success') {
        console.log('FAIL to load the address');
    } else {

        if (page.injectJs("jquery-1.3.2.min.js")) {
            console.log("jQuery loaded...");
        }   

        console.log(page.content);
    }

    phantom.exit();
});
```

However, what I get is the Chinese version since I am located in Taiwan.
My Platform is Macbook Pro, Mountain Lion (English Version).

How can I change the language for what I parse? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In which language you get the page depends on implementation of site. Worse scenario for you if site decides language based on your location. The only work around for this would be to use proxy server from English region.

**UPDATE**

in case of google.com use the following url

```
https://www.google.com/?hl=en
```

instead of

```
https://www.google.com/
```